# Problem with texify

Tags: errors

I don't know what is the cause of this problem. I actually saw that the texify.log file is empty. Could that be the problem?

Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:/Users/PB/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Comment: That's the problem with texify --  it doesn't give good error messages. You can try to compile with it on the command line -- sometimes you can get a clue what is the problem. I simply never use it.

Comment: I assume you are trying to highlight some program code. How about using the `listings` package instead?